# Simplifying a logical expression

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I'm looking for a way to simplify this logical expression:

```
((x == y) and (x > 0 or z > 0))
or
((x != y) and (x > 0 and y > 0 and z > 0))
```

All variables are non-negative integers.

I thought about using [Karnaugh Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map), but my variables aren't boolean, which kind of complicates things.

Then I figured I should probably translate that into a set of boolean variables, for example:

- `a = (x == y)`
- `b = (x > 0)`
- `c = (y > 0)`
- `d = (z > 0)`

But those boolean variables aren't exactly independent of each other.

For example, if `a` is `true`, then `b` must be equal to `c`.

Any idea would be very much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let us define propositions (in fact propositional functions) $p$, $q$, and $r$ as follows:
$$
p \colon \  (x == y),
$$
$$
q \colon \  (x > 0 \mbox{ or } z > 0), 
$$
and
$$
r \colon \  (x > 0 \mbox{ and } y > 0 \mbox{ and } z > 0).
$$
Then we have
$$
r \implies q,
$$
and the given logical expression is
$$
(p \land  q ) \lor  \big( (\lnot p) \land  r \big),
$$
which we can operate upon as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
(p \land  q ) \lor  \big( (\lnot p) \land  r \big) &= \big( p \lor \big( (\lnot p) \land  r \big) \big) \land \big( q \lor \big( (\lnot p) \land  r \big) \big) \\
&= \big( p \lor (\lnot p)  \big) \land (p \lor r) \land \big( q \lor (\lnot p) \big) \land (q \lor r) \\
&= T \land (p \lor r) \land \big( q \lor (\lnot p) \big) \land (q \lor r) \\
&= (p \lor r) \land \big( q \lor (\lnot p) \big) \land (q \lor r) \\
&= 
\end{align}
$$

Hope this helps.